# Special Font for Authors

Tags: fonts, author, paper

Some papers use a special font for authors, even when it is part of a name of a mathematical object or something similar. What is the font and the general opinion on doing this? An example is given below. [image: Example where the name "Reissner-Nordstrøm is in a different font.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It is not a special font, it is just a small caps shape in a normal font (looks like Latin Modern). In particular, it is used in French bibliography styles.

Comment: Well, do you have the pdf file? Then you can check it for the used fonts ...

Comment: Usually small caps are generated with `\textsc{Small Caps}` if your font supports them. The example seems to be a bit inconsistent, though. Why is Reissner in small caps bit Nordstroem not?

Comment: Thank you! I seem to have picked an example where the author was inconsistent. What is your opinion on the use of it?

Comment: You may also want to check the spelling of Nordstroem, most Google hits have "Nordström" (Gunnar Nordström was a Finnish physicist, so his name is probably either Swedish or Finnish [my money would be on Swedish] in origin and both languages use `ö` not `ø`).

Comment: You might have asked the wrong person here, I'm quite fond of small caps for people's names, especially in the bibliography (if there are many names in the text I will worry about overdoing things at some point). But I have the feeling that many people (especially when it comes to English or German publications) consider this practice antiquated (the French would seem to think differently, apparently the practice is quite widespread there).

Answer (score 1):

A short code for your question, taking the comments fully into consideration. In The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List of Scott Pakin there are also the due explanations how to use the particular characters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
extreme \textsc{Reissner}-Nordstr\o m-L\"{o}sung
\end{document}
```